# Существует что то типа ULogin только что б твиттер тоже работал?

Tags: ulogin

Надо написать частичное заполнение формы через соц сети. Помог ULogin - сделал через вконтакте, фейсбук и гугл+, но надо еще и твиттер, а в ULogin  проблема с ним

Comment: если это важно, то сайт на zend framework